# How to set the items of a ComboBox into another one

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm populating a VBA ComboBox with some data from a Workshet. As it is populated depending on the choice of the user, sometimes some levels are should not be populated, because they do not have data. When such a thing happens, I want to populate the items of a ComboBox with the same of another. How can a do that?

I think if somebody teaches me how to loop through the items of a ComboBox, I will the able to do what I want.

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you loop through a combobox.

```
Dim intComboItem As Integer

For intComboItem = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
    MsgBox Me.ComboBox1.List(intComboItem)
Next
```